# .after method Python seems so to be called immediately

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def __show_square_left(square):
square.pack(anchor = "nw", padx = (100,0), pady = (200,0))
print("square shown")
self.__SimonTask.after(ms_visible, __Clear_Square(square))
return

def __show_square_right(square):
square.pack(anchor = "ne", padx = (0,100), pady = (200,0))
print("square shown")
self.__SimonTask.after(ms_visible, __Clear_Square(square))
return

def __Clear_Square(square):
square.pack_forget()
print("square deleted")
print()
self.__SimonTask.after(ms_between, __show_square)
```

my problem is that my code seems to completely ignore the after from __show_square_left and __show_square_right because it immediately runs __Clear_Square whatever number there is filled in for ms_visible. 
The after in __Clear_Square, on the other hand, does work.

I'm creating a program where I'm showing squares (red or blue at random) and they are displayed left or right at random

and to do that i let them appear for a given amount of ms  (ms_visible , for which I am filling in 2000) and when it dissapears the other one should show after a given amount of ms (ms_between, which I also set to 2000 to test it out)

To show and hide the squares, the program runs through the function __show_square, which results in the function __show_square_left or __show_square_right being runned
These functions do the same:

1. pack the square (show it)
2. after ms_visible, it should run the command __Clear_Square (which removes the square from the window out of sight)(gewijzigd)

and thats where my problem is

it already runs __Clear_Square before the time has passed, so the squares happen to be shown and deleted at the same time, resulting in the square never being shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called immediately because you actually called it immediately when you did `__Clear_Square(square)`. That calls `__Clear_Square` immediately, then uses its return value as the callback (since it returns `None`, this means no callback is performed).

You want:

```
self.__SimonTask.after(ms_visible, __Clear_Square, square)
```

which passes a reference to the `__Clear_Square` function as the callback (*without* calling it), and `square` as the argument to call it with.

Comment: Aahhh! Of course! Thank you! I'm still learning Python, and never used an after with an argument in the called function before. Haven't seen an example before.